# Help! computer still booting windows 7 after having ubuntu server installed!

Tags: server

So my machine I am installing ubuntu server on at the moment has windows 7 installed so I plug in my bootable USB go through the installation and it says its finished but it still boots Windows 7!? does anyone know why it does this if you do then please tell me.

Thanks

Robin

Comment: If you go into your BIOS, what does it show for boot options? Also if you look at disk manager, do you see Linux partitions?

Comment: Hello thanks for the repsonse so quick i have checked my BIOS settings and it says i can boot from a usb a cd and my hard drive and check disk MNG and i do not see any linux partions.

Comment: Hello i have fixed my issue the ubuntu server installed on a different partion and after going into my boot menu and clicking on my second partion it is now booting into ubuntu server.